# Improve Execution Time

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic, dynamic-programming, execution-time

How can the following program execution time improved.
I have used dynamic programming in both "recursive" as well as "prime" function.
But not getting the efficient execution time.

QUESTION:There is a wall of size 4xN in the victim's house where. The victim also has an infinite
supply of bricks of size 4x1 and 1x4 in her house. In every
configuration, the wall has to be completely covered using the bricks. Gale Bertram wants to know the total number of ways in which the bricks can be arranged on the wall so that a new configuration arises every time. 
Let the number of Configuration = M.

So, he wants Patrick to calculate the number of prime numbers (say P) up to M (i.e. <= M). 
You are required to help Patrick correctly solve the puzzle.

Sample Input
The first line of input will contain an integer T followed by T lines each containing an
integer N.

Sample Output
Print exactly one line of output for each test case. The output should contain the
number P.
Constraints
1<=T<=20
1<=N<=40

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
class Solution{
    public static int[] b = new int[217287];
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = stdin.nextInt();
    int[] a = new int[41];
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            a[j] = 1;          //till n<=3, number of possiblities = 1. These will work as base cases.
        }
        a[4] = 2;
    for(int x=0;x<t;x++){
        int n = stdin.nextInt();
        for(int i=5;i<=n;i++){
            a[i] = -1;         //initialise all value in the array as -1.
        }
        if(n<4)
            System.out.println("0"); // if n<4, number of possibilities =1. So no prime number before that is 0.
        else{
                     //for n=4, possibilities = 2. This is a base case.
        int num1 = recursive(a,n);          // storing number of possibilities in num1.
        int num2 = prime(num1);    //calling to calculate number of prime numbers before or equal to num1.
        System.out.println(num2);
        }
    }
}
public static int recursive(int[] a, int n){
    if(a[n]!=-1)                             // retrieving a[n] value if already calculated.
        return a[n];
    else{
        a[n] = recursive(a,n-1) + recursive(a,n-4); // calling recursively.If we fill with a 4*1 first tile then number 
                                                    //tiles left is n-1(try visualising).If we fill 1*4 tile first
                                                    // we have n-4 tile left.
        return a[n];
    }
}
public static int prime(int n){
    int count = 0;
    if(b[n]!=0)
        return b[n];
    else{
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
        if(b[i]!=0){
            count = b[i];
        }
        else{
        int flag = 0;           
        for(int j=2;j<=i/2;j++){
            if(i%j==0){
                flag = 1;
                break;
                }
            }
    if(flag==0){
        count++;
        b[i]=count;
    }
    }
    }
    return count;
    }
}
```

}

I got a timeout(more than 4s) for the following input.
20
35
23
25
38
4
35
19
8
23
35
3
36
12
10
30
13
18
31
40
37

Comment: Have you tried using a cpu profiler, or any other techniques for reducing CPU time?

Comment: Since you have currently working code, and you want to try and improve it, you might have better luck over at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: given that you already have the recurrence relation for `a`, you can run another program to generate the entries of `a`, and use that instead of your recursive function. You might even in the same program create a sieve, but a sieve is fast anyhow.

Comment: @Ben Can you give more details about "sieve"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to further optimize your `int prime(int n)` function. (Of course, you can use any efficient algorithm from the 'net, but:) To avoid doing the same calculations again and again note that you can compute `prime(n+m)` faster if you already have `prime(n)`.

(I think you were already thinking in that direction because you are using some 'cache' for already calculated figures.)

Edit:
See Ordous' answer #2 :)

Edit2:

To elaborate a little more on the idea:

Q: If I know the number `c` of primes `<= X`, what is the number of primes `<= (X+1)`?

A: `c`, if `X+1` is *not* a prime, or `c+1` if `X+1` *is* a prime. Like so:

```
public static int prime2( final int n ) {
    int count;
    if ( n <= 2 ) {
        count = 1;
    } else {
        count = prime2(n-1);
        if ( isPrime(n) ) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Then add your caching approach to store the result of any computed `prime2(x)` for later use.

Comment: I am storing the number of prime values in a global array b. And retrieving it to avoid repeated calculation. Can you please give some detail about your optimisation process.

Comment: As Ordous says: You are already 'caching', for example, the result of `prime(1000)`, but you are *not* using this result the next time you need to calculate `prime(1001)` although you could do that.

Comment: i did some correction but still not getting. please check the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are making 2 major mistakes here (or rather allowing for 2 inefficiencies):

1. You are re-initializing and recomputing your `a` array with every loop. Those don't change, just reuse the result from last time by allocating an array of size 40 initially (You also may want to consider better naming conventions...)
2. You are **NOT** using dynamic programming in the "prime" part of the task. Dynamic programming is about saving intermediate results for future use, you are saving just the answer in hopes of it being used again (it's not going to be used again, since `n` will be unique for a unique `N` - again *naming conventions*)

Part 1 is not likely to be adding much time since the calculations are trivial and N <= 40.
 Part 2 is where you screw up. Instead of saving only `b[n]` you could do the following: looping from 1 to `n` fill up `b` with the number of primes less than or equal to `i` where `i` is the index. This is done in a single prime check - if `i` is prime then put `b[i-1]` otherwise `b[i-1] + 1`. This will mean you only check if a number is prime *once per number* (In your current implementation you check it 20 times). You could possibly add a sieve as in the comments to further increase performance, but the above is likely to give enough of a speedup to have 0.1 second runtime on mediocre machines with the given constraints.

Comment: public static int prime(int n){
        int count = 0;
  if(b[n]!=0)
   return b[n];
  else{
        for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
   if(b[i]!=0){
    count = b[i];
   }
   else{
   int flag = 0;           
            for(int j=2;j<=i/2;j++){
                if(i%j==0){
                    flag = 1;
     break;
     }
    }
        if(flag==0){
            count++;
   b[i]=count;
        }
        }
  }
        return count;
  }// is this what you were saying?

Comment: @Torrtuga please don't post code in comments, it's horrible to read... But yes, that looks much better. You still have a couple of mistakes in it: take the `b[i]=count` out of the conditional, otherwise you will be recalculating the results for primes, also loop to `sqrt(i)`, not `i/2`. Also it's customary to use a `boolean` as a flag, instead of an `int`

Comment: THANKS. GOT the output in required time. sqrt(i) really made the difference.Thanks a lot!!